# linq-to-sql joins with multiple from clauses syntax vs. traditional join syntax

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

What the difference between writing a join using 2 `from` clauses and a `where` like this:

```
var SomeQuery = from a in MyDC.Table1
                from b in MyDC.Table2
                where a.SomeCol1 == SomeParameter && a.SomeCol2 === b.SomeCol1
```

and writing a `join` using the join operator.

This is for a `join` on 2 tables but of course, sometimes, we need to join even more tables and we need to combine other `from` clauses with `where` if we choose the syntax above.

I know both syntax queries return the same data but I was wondering if there's a performance difference, or another kind of difference, that would conclusively favor one syntax over the other.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This question is actually answered pretty good in these two.

[INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

[INNER JOIN vs multiple table names in "FROM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118562/inner-join-vs-multiple-table-names-in-from)

I've included two examples on how three different LINQ expressions will be translated into SQL.

**Implicit join:**

```
from prod in Articles
from kat in MainGroups
where kat.MainGroupNo == prod.MainGroupNo
select new { kat.Name, prod.ArticleNo }
```

Will be translated into

```
SELECT [t1].[Name], [t0].[ArticleNo]
FROM [dbo].[Article] AS [t0], [dbo].[MainGroup] AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[MainGroupNo] = [t0].[MainGroupNo]
```

**Inner join:**

```
from prod in Articles
join kat in MainGroups on prod.MainGroupNo equals kat.MainGroupNo
select new { kat.Name, prod.ArticleNo }
```

Will be translated into

```
SELECT [t1].[Name], [t0].[ArticleNo]
FROM [dbo].[Article] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MainGroup] AS [t1] ON [t0].[MainGroupNo] = [t1].[MainGroupNo]
```

**Left outer join:**

```
from prod in Articles
join g1 in MainGroups on prod.MainGroupNo equals g1.MainGroupNo into prodGroup
from kat in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { kat.Name, prod.ArticleNo }
```

Will be translated into

```
SELECT [t1].[Name] AS [Name], [t0].[ArticleNo]
FROM [dbo].[Article] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MainGroup] AS [t1] ON [t0].[MainGroupNo] = [t1].[MainGroupNo]
```

If you want to test how your expressions will be translated into SQL, I recommend that you try [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It's an awesome tool for figuring out this kind of stuff.

Comment: So what's better? 2 or more from clauses or 2 or more join clauses?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line the join clause seems preferable.

Answer (score -3):

```
var result = from a in DB.classA
from b in DB.classB
where a.id.Equals(b.id)
select new{a.b};
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, nor does it provide any explanation.