# Select using 2 instance of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Normally if I want to get an instance from table I use the following script :

```
SELECT STD_NAME FROM STUDENT S1 ,STUDENT S2
```

suppose student as an inner query like :

```
SELECT  std_name  FROM student, grades where student.id=grade.std_id) as S1
```

how can I use this inner query to make 2 instances ,with less coding.

shall I do some thing like :

```
(SELECT std_name  FROM student where student.id>=10) as S1 ,S2
```

I am using sql server 2008

Comment: Can you provide sample output?  The question "how can I use this inner query to make 2 instances, with less coding" doesn't make sense (at least to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to create 2 instances?
They are equal.

But try:

```
( (Select x from A where A.x>=10) as S1) as S2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `Table1, Table2` which could have [unintended consequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118562/inner-join-vs-multiple-table-names-in-from), like

```
SELECT std_name, grades.grade 
FROM student 
INNER JOIN grades 
ON student.id=grades.std_id
WHERE student.id>=10
```

See examples for [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp), [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), [RIGHT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp) and [FULL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp)