# Inner join 3 tables and calculate the average value on a field

Tags: mysql

There are 3 tables:

1. medics:

   - IDM (id_medic) (primary key)
   - 1st name
   - 2nd name
   - specialty
2. patients:

   - IDP (id_patient) (primary key)
   - name
   - DOB (date of birth)
3. visits:

   - id
   - id_medic
   - id_patient

I would like to find out **the average age of patients for each specialty**.

```
SELECT specialty, AVG(year(curdate()) - year(patients.DOB))
FROM medics, patients, visits 
WHERE medics.IDM = visits.medics GROUP by specialty;
```

The query above shows me on each line the average of all patients.

Comment: I have also tried to group by speciality,patient.name but I fell i'm close but not cigar

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
SELECT
Speciality,
ROUND(AVG(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(DOB)),0) AS Years
FROM visits

INNER JOIN medics
ON visits.IdMedic = medics.Id

INNER JOIN patients
ON visits.IdPatient = patients.Id

GROUP BY Speciality
```

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IdMedic` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdPatient` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `patients` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOB` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `medics` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Speciality` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thank yoou very much could you please explain to me sir? I would also like to know If there is a difference between an inner join or a select from multiple tables as I wanted to do

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118562/inner-join-vs-multiple-table-names-in-from

Comment: I hope I will be able to help you

Comment: Very useful thanks for hint i'm new  here. Can I give u some medal:)?

Comment: Yes! Click in "This answer is useful". Check the post as solved. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please tell me how to exclude pediatric speciality from this query?

Comment: Yes. Add this before of GROUP BY : WHERE Speciality NOT IN('pediatric')

Comment: It could also work with speciality not like 'pediatric'?

Comment: WHERE Speciality NOT LIKE('%pediatric%')