# Mysql: Select data from two tables, where email address column matches in both

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get data from two tables they are wp_users, and opt_in.

The tables both have an email column (the only common between them), and I'm trying to get results that look like this, where I have the wp_users login name, and the rest of the opt_in table data:

`wp_users.user_login, email, opt_in.first_name, opt_in.last_name`

The query I've written is too slow.  With around 100k rows in each table, I haven't get results without putting a limit on the query.  I must not be using the right tool for the job.  Show me the error of my ways.

Here's an example of the query which gives me the right data, but is very slow:

```
SELECT wp_users.user_email, opt_in.first_name, opt_in.last_name 
FROM wp_users, opt_in 
WHERE wp_users.user_email = opt_in.email;
```

Comment: You might want to consider indexes on your tables to speed up your query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) on that column.

For email fields you can use UNIQUE index it will also help you to remove duplicate entries.

In case if you want to check existing index's on your table. Use below query in phpmyadmin / mysql console

```
show indexes from TABLENAME;
```

Comment: You pointed me at the right direction, so I'll accept the answer.

ALTER TABLE  `wp_users` ADD INDEX (  `user_email` ) ;
ALTER TABLE  `opt_in` ADD INDEX (  `email` ) ;

That's all I did... now it's running at light speed.  Unique indexes couldn't be used, but that's OK.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- Try using JOIN - 
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

> SELECT wp_users.user_email, opt_in.first_name, opt_in.last_name 
>       FROM wp_users 
>       INNER JOIN (opt_in) 
>       ON (opt_in.email = wp_users.user_email)

- use EXPLAIN to understand what's going on
- and as mentioned, Indexes play a huge role in increasing speed of query execution
- Few other links explaining why anyone should use JOIN instead of multiple Select

  - [SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)
  - [Left join or select from multiple table using comma (,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779174/left-join-or-select-from-multiple-table-using-comma)